# How to count the occurrences of a value in a key?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have already checked the solution, Dictionary: How to count frequency of values in list - Python3, in stackoverflow as well as other options in google. Instead of getting the amount of occurrences from a key. I receive the amounts of characters from the words but not the amount of words actually.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

content = "Note.csv"
collector = {}
with open(content, 'r') as file:
    genres = csv.DictReader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in genres:
        collector = {"Genre": f'{row["others"]}',
                     "Title": f'{row["title"]}'}
        print(collector)
        colors = ['r','g']
        for k, v in collector.items():
            D = defaultdict(list)
            for i, item in enumerate(v):
                D[item].append(i)
            D = {k: v for k, v in D.items()}
            print(k, D)
```

Note.csv contains the following:

```
title, author, year, others, note
Everything,Nobody,2222,Fiction,This is just something of everything!
Nothing,Everybody,1111,Romance,This is nothing of anything!
Pokemon,Pikachu,1999,Fiction,Once upon time.
```

The final result should then actually be or something like this.
1: Romance; 2: Fiction

From the result I want to be able to create a pie chart.

As always, thank you very much for your helpful comments and answers!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just counting the number of each genre, you can use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(content, 'r') as file:
    genres = csv.DictReader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
    c = Counter(row["others"] for row in genres)

print(c)
# Counter({'Fiction': 2, 'Romance': 1})
```

Comment: As always, thank you very much. I am embarrassed that it is such a simple solution. Anyway, thank you very much. It works perfectly!